# Failed in getting all methods from a ClassLibrary Project file i.e DLL file in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, methods, reference

I have Created a DLL from ClassLibrary Project with 3 methods but it shows only one Method from that DLL file. Why this happen? Why i cant see all the Methods that are in DLL? I have Updated Build the ClassLibrary Project and again referenced in the Web Project but still it shows only one method amongst 3Methods. Plz Help...!

In DLL file 3Methods:
Method 1:

```
private DataTable SearchConstituencyDetails(int ConstituencyNumber, int Partnumber, int SerialInPart, string tabltoconnect, string conString)
{
// Some code here
}
```

Method 2:

```
public DataTable NameSearch(string searchExpression, string sAge, char language, string conString)
{
//Some code here
}
```

Method 3:

```
private DataRow SearchConstTable(int ConstituencyNumber, int Partnumber, int SerialInPart, string conString)
{
//some code here
}
```

but am able to retrive only:  **public DataTable NameSearch(string searchExpression, string sAge, char language, string conString)** method from this DLL in asp.net project and not all three mothods why does this happen..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Private accessors to Public, it will work.

Comment: Yes now i got it..! Thanks Deepesh!

Comment: @Shekar WC please mark the answer as correct if it has solved your problem